# Finding Consecutive Matching Elements in Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am having a slight issue with this problem. All the answers check out for all of the calls except for one, which I don't get.

`contains({1, 2, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3})` returns false when it should be true.

Prompt:

Write a static method named contains that accepts two arrays of integers `a1` and `a2` as parameters and that returns a boolean value indicating whether or not `a2`'s sequence of elements appears in `a1` (true for yes, false for no). The sequence of elements in `a2` may appear anywhere in `a1` but must appear consecutively and in the same order. For example, if variables called `list1` and `list2` store the following values:

```
int[] list1 = {1, 6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8};
int[] list2 = {1, 2, 1};
```

Then the call of contains(list1, list2) should return true because list2's sequence of values `{1, 2, 1}` is contained in list1 starting at index 5. If list2 had stored the values `{2, 1, 2}`, the call of contains(list1, list2) would return false because list1 does not contain that sequence of values. Any two lists with identical elements are considered to contain each other, so a call such as contains(list1, list1) should return true.

You may assume that both arrays passed to your method will have lengths of at least 1. You may not use any Strings to help you solve this problem, nor methods that produce Strings such as Arrays.toString.

Code:

```
public static boolean contains(int[] first, int[] second) {
    int secondCount = 0; // Indicates where to start on second array

    if (first.length < second.length) { // If second array is longer than first
        return false;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<first.length; i++) { // goes through each element in first array
        if (first[i] == second[secondCount]) { // If elements match 
            secondCount++; // increment by one and move onto next elem on second
            if (secondCount == second.length) { // If complete match
                return true;
            }
        } else { // resets count
            secondCount = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns `false` due to the way you have constructed your loop. Below, I outline your method's runtime.

```
i = 0; secondCount = 0;
{1, 2, 1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3}
 ^               ^
 1 == 1 ? true

i = 1; secondCount = 1;
{1, 2, 1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3}
    ^               ^
 2 == 2 ? true

i = 2; secondCount = 2;
{1, 2, 1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3}
       ^               ^
 1 == 3 ? false

i = 3; secondCount = 0;
{1, 2, 1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3}
          ^      ^
 2 == 1 ? false

i = 3; secondCount = 0;
{1, 2, 1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3}
             ^   ^
 3 == 1 ? false

return false;
```

The problem is that if the boolean equation `first[i] == second[secondCount]` is false, then `secondCount` is reset while **`i` is still advanced**. Thus, `contains({1, 2, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3});` will always return `false`.

Consider adding a `continue` to your code whenever `first[i] == second[secondCount]` fails to prevent `i` advancing.

Answer (score 0):

When resetting `secondCount` from non-zero to zero also decrement `i` by one.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code-->

```
public static boolean contains(int[] first, int[] second) {
int secondCount = 0; // Indicates where to start on second array

if (first.length < second.length) { // If second array is longer than first
    return false;
}

for (int i=0; i<first.length; i++) { // goes through each element in first array
    if (first[i] == second[secondCount]) { // If elements match 
        secondCount++; // increment by one and move onto next elem on second
        if (secondCount == second.length) { // If complete match
            return true;
        }
    } else { // resets count
        secondCount = 0;
        i--;          //ADD THIS
    }
}
return false;
}
```

(Using your example of list1={1,2,1,2,3} and list2={1,2,3}) 'i' has to be decremented because when initially list1[0] and list1[1] were equal to list2[0] and list2[1] respectively and comparison of list1[2] was made to list2[2] which is false, you only decrement second count and you do i++, hence when you start once again, you compare list1[3] with list2[0] which is false but you should have compared list1[2] instead of list1[3].

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a lot of codes similar to mine but I think this is a better solution!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] list1 = {1, 6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8};
        int[] list2 = {1, 2, 1};
        boolean presence = contains(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(presence);
}

public static boolean contains(int[] list1, int[] list2){
    if (list1.length < list2.length){
        return false;
    }
    int count = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
        if (list1[i] == list2[counter]){
            count++;
            counter++;
            if (count == list2.length){
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you are resetting `counter` every time you do not match, but not `count` I think you are going to get false positives.  Also, because you do not backtrack, you are going to miss some matches, when for example the input is:

    { 1 6 2 1 2 1 2 1 3 5 }
    { 1 2 1 3 }